# Постановка ударения

Tags: фонетика

Как правильно ставить ударение: "не дАл" или "нЕ дал"? Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ударение передвигается на частицу НЕ в формах прошедшего времени (за исключением формы женского рода) с такими глаголами:

— быть — нЕ был, нЕ было, нЕ были; но: не былА;

— дать — нЕ дал, нЕ дало, нЕ дали; но: не далА;

— жить — нЕ жил, нЕ жило, нЕ жили; но: не жилА;

— пить — нЕ пил, нЕ пило, нЕ пили; но: не пилА.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы указать источник, в котором указано ударение нЕ пил.

Answer (score 2):

Предпочтительно: *н**е** дал,* но допустимо и *не д**а**л.*